# Get Current Time - Server or Client Side

Tags: php, javascript, html

Is there any server or client side way to determine their location and get the local time.

I'd like it to also update in real time, e.g. hour, mins, secs.

I'd prefer it if I can use PHP / JavaScript (jQuery included) or something like that.

Comment: have you tried googling for "javascript clock"?

Comment: I believe this post would solve your question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8090549/how-to-get-user-timezone-using-jquery

Comment: You probably want to use server time (in case client's time is incorrect) with PHP.

Comment: I think the `Date()` constructor in JavaScript provides the time from the user's PC, which should be set in his time zone.  You could keep executing the `Date().getTime()` method every second with a timer and just have it update the innerText of some element on the page (or whatever you need to do with it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want this

```
setInterval(function(){
    var dt=new Date(), h=dt.getHours(), m=dt.getMinutes(), s=dt.getSeconds(),
    curTime= pad(h)+':'+pad(m)+':'+pad(s); 
    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML=curTime;
}, 500);
function pad(n) { return ("0" + n).slice(-2); }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/ahejet/3/edit).

Comment: Is it possible to have a 0 before single numbers? For example, 12:02:09

Comment: Looking good. I thought JavaScript would have an easier way to show this. Seems not. Thanks for your help!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18253/discussion-between-user1658756-and-sheikh-heera)

Answer (score 1):

You can try using jquery localtime plugin. Take a look [here]: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-localtime/wiki/Usage

Comment: Yes, it does... All you need to do is to pass your UTC time (example: an event UTC 10:00) and viewer will have it translated to his/her current time based on location...

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript you can easily get the current date and time using the Date object;

`var now = new Date();`

This will get the local client machine time.