# Reloading page after detecting user-timezone. Will there be SEO penalty?

Tags: javascript, php, datetime, seo, web-crawler

I'm creating a site using PHP, and it needs to display the time on the page according to the user's timezone.

After some searching, I couldn't find a server-side way to do it, and all of the solutions required detecting the timezone using JS and refreshing the page. Such as : [PHP timestamp date to user timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13339086/php-timestamp-date-to-user-timezone)

Now, this works. I am saving the timezone on user's cookies so the site doesn't refresh again. But I'm wondering if there is an SEO penalty if the crawlers detect a refresh upon visiting a site/page for the first time?

Answer (score 0):

I would not advise a "refresh" when the user loads the page just for that. You can utilize the method recommended in the link you posted, and have PHP save the timezone to a cookie, so that it can read from that cookie next time the user loads the page.

An easy solution would be to display the time on the front-end in PHP, and use a JavaScript framework, such as [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/), to display in the user's current timezone.