# adapting posted time based on timezone

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a script that outputs some data along whith a tag like "added 1 hour ago" .
Now, if the timezone on the server is the same as the user;s timezone it will do it fine.

I know that user's timezone can be obtained by JavaScript, but how do I sent offset to the PHP script before the data is displayed? a `body onload` function? append a parameter to the main page that will show the content?

timezone on server is set to UTC

thx

Comment: Why is this important? If the user is in another timezone, the post is still 1 hour old. Use the server time for both.

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8090549/how-to-get-user-timezone-using-jquery

Answer (score 2):

You can get the user's timezone in javascript and then make a ajax request to some file and in that file you can do like this

```
$tz = $_POST['tz'];
date_default_timezone_set($tz);
echo  date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```