# Get name of time zone

Tags: jquery, timezone

Can I get the name of the time zone of the client by using jQuery?

Example: Pacific S.A. Standard Time, Greenwich Standard Time, like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zones_by_country

[Timezonelist](http://vi.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=M%C3%BAi_gi%E1%BB%9D&oldid=39044)

Comment: The output of `new Date()` is `Wed Aug 14 2013 22:02:13 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)`, can you use that?

Comment: There's no native JS/jQuery function that does this.

One way of doing this is to combine JS (AJAX) with server side code, such as PHP.

Look at the top answer in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8090549/how-to-get-user-timezone-using-jquery) thread. It combines JS and PHP and does what you want.

Comment: @ItayItai You don't think my answer satisfies the requirement? It's the same name from the list the OP gave

Comment: @Juan Mendes: You're right, but I was explaining the idea of using AJAX for this mission. He can be more flexible with the server side code (assuming he needs something more specific than your answer)

Comment: @Juan Mendes In Safari on Mac , it not Wed Aug 14 2013 22:02:13 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time), it like Wed Aug 14 2013 22:02:13 GMT-0700 (PCI). Not my anwser i need, I need get Timezone Name like Pacific S.A. Standard Time, Greenwich Standard Time . thank you for response

Comment: @NathanNguyễn There is enough information through the comments and answer for you to solve your problem, you should post what you come up with.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript timezone information how to get America/Los\_Angeles (or equivalent)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22618056/javascript-timezone-information-how-to-get-america-los-angeles-or-equivalent)

Comment: @NathanNguyễn  see this plugin it will give you timezone name and many more http://kevalbhatt.github.io/WorldMapGenerator/

Comment: No need for jQuery. The question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9772955/how-can-i-get-the-timezone-name-in-javascript is essentially the same as this and has several useful answers.

Answer (score 53):

> Can I get the name of the time zone of the client by using jQuery?

No.  jQuery has only one date/time function, which is `$.now()`.

If you meant *JavaScript*, the answer is still *no*.  You can only obtain a time zone *offset* from `date.getTimezoneOffset()`.  You can't get a time zone - at least not in all browsers.  Refer to [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info)'s section titled: `"Time Zone != Offset"`

You can *guess* at the time zone, by using the [jsTimeZoneDetect](https://github.com/pellepim/jstimezonedetect) library, but it is just a guess.  It may or may not be accurate.

You can also now use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) with the [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone) add on.  It now supports time zone guessing with `moment.tz.guess()`.

If you can guarantee your users are running in an environment that fully supports the  [ECMAScript Internationalization API](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-402/1.0/), you can get the user's time zone like this:

```
Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone
```

You can review the [compatibility table](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/esintl/#test-DateTimeFormat_resolvedOptions().timeZone_defaults_to_the_host_environment), under `DateTimeFormat` - `resolvedOptions().timezone defaults to the host environment` to determine which environments this will work in.

Honestly, the best thing to do is to just give your user a screen somewhere that they can select their timezone.  You might use a drop-down list, or you might use a map-based timezone picker - [like this one](https://github.com/dosx/timezone-picker).  You can use jsTimeZoneDetect as a default value, but your user should be able to change it.

Also, all of these are going to give you an IANA time zone identifier, such as `America/Los_Angeles`.  But the examples you gave appear to be Windows time zone ids (for use with `TimeZoneInfo` in .net).  You should read [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info), and then also this question: [How to translate between Windows and IANA time zones?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17348807/634824)

Comment: @KevalBhatt - Nice!  I'll keep that in mind for questions about time zone pickers.  It's a good alternative for the one I linked to above.  Thanks!

Comment: `(new Date).toString().split('(')[1].slice(0, -1)`

Comment: @Sami - that's not reliable.  The results could be anything.  The implementations vary considerably across browsers, and there is no spec.

Comment: With the compatibility on Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions(), it would seem this is the best option now-a-days. Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

The output of `new Date()` is `Wed Aug 14 2013 22:02:13 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)`, can you use that? If you don't need the official name, you can just use what's in between the parentheses

```
function getTimeZone() {
    return /\((.*)\)/.exec(new Date().toString())[1];
}

getTimeZone(); // Pacific Daylight Time
```

Comment: In Safari on Mac , it not Wed Aug 14 2013 22:02:13 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time), it like Wed Aug 14 2013 22:02:13 GMT-0700 (PCI). Not my anwser i need, I need get Timezone Name like Pacific S.A. Standard Time, Greenwich Standard Time . thank you for response

Comment: @Juan - That response is going to be highly browser, language, and OS specific.

Comment: @MattJohnson Which may be a good thing if you're used to seeing your time zone in your own OS, browser and language :) and you don't have a need for official time zone names.

Comment: This is helpful if you want "Pacific Daylight Time" instead of "America/Los_Angeles". But @MattJohnson-Pint is right, this isn't very robust. Instead, here's a browser/language/OS-inspecific solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70376901/775283

Answer (score 14):

As an alternative below is the way to get timezone with **pure javascript**:

```
(new Date).toString().split('(')[1].slice(0, -1)
```

Answer (score 8):

Get the current timezone standard name:

```
function getTimezoneName() {
    var timeSummer = new Date(Date.UTC(2005, 6, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0));
    var summerOffset = -1 * timeSummer.getTimezoneOffset();
    var timeWinter = new Date(Date.UTC(2005, 12, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0));
    var winterOffset = -1 * timeWinter.getTimezoneOffset();
    var timeZoneHiddenField;

    if (-720 == summerOffset && -720 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Dateline Standard Time'; }
    else if (-660 == summerOffset && -660 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'UTC-11'; }
    else if (-660 == summerOffset && -660 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Samoa Standard Time'; }
    else if (-660 == summerOffset && -600 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Hawaiian Standard Time'; }
    else if (-570 == summerOffset && -570 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField.value = 'Pacific/Marquesas'; }
    //                else if (-540 == summerOffset && -600 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField.value = 'America/Adak'; }
    //                else if (-540 == summerOffset && -540 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField.value = 'Pacific/Gambier'; }
    else if (-480 == summerOffset && -540 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Alaskan Standard Time'; }
    //                else if (-480 == summerOffset && -480 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Pacific/Pitcairn'; }
    else if (-420 == summerOffset && -480 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Pacific Standard Time'; }
    else if (-420 == summerOffset && -420 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'US Mountain Standard Time'; }
    else if (-360 == summerOffset && -420 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Mountain Standard Time'; }
    else if (-360 == summerOffset && -360 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Central America Standard Time'; }
    //                else if (-360 == summerOffset && -300 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Pacific/Easter'; }
    else if (-300 == summerOffset && -360 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Central Standard Time'; }
    else if (-300 == summerOffset && -300 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'SA Pacific Standard Time'; }
    else if (-240 == summerOffset && -300 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Eastern Standard Time'; }
    else if (-270 == summerOffset && -270 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Venezuela Standard Time'; }
    else if (-240 == summerOffset && -240 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'SA Western Standard Time'; }
    else if (-240 == summerOffset && -180 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Central Brazilian Standard Time'; }
    else if (-180 == summerOffset && -240 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Atlantic Standard Time'; }
    else if (-180 == summerOffset && -180 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Montevideo Standard Time'; }
    else if (-180 == summerOffset && -120 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'E. South America Standard Time'; }
    else if (-150 == summerOffset && -210 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Mid-Atlantic Standard Time'; }
    else if (-120 == summerOffset && -180 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'America/Godthab'; }
    else if (-120 == summerOffset && -120 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'SA Eastern Standard Time'; }
    else if (-60 == summerOffset && -60 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Cape Verde Standard Time'; }
    else if (0 == summerOffset && -60 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Azores Daylight Time'; }
    else if (0 == summerOffset && 0 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Morocco Standard Time'; }
    else if (60 == summerOffset && 0 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'GMT Standard Time'; }
    else if (60 == summerOffset && 60 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Africa/Algiers'; }
    else if (60 == summerOffset && 120 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Namibia Standard Time'; }
    else if (120 == summerOffset && 60 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Central European Standard Time'; }
    else if (120 == summerOffset && 120 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'South Africa Standard Time'; }
    else if (180 == summerOffset && 120 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'GTB Standard Time'; }
    else if (180 == summerOffset && 180 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'E. Africa Standard Time'; }
    else if (240 == summerOffset && 180 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Russian Standard Time'; }
    else if (240 == summerOffset && 240 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Arabian Standard Time'; }
    else if (270 == summerOffset && 210 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Iran Standard Time'; }
    else if (270 == summerOffset && 270 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Afghanistan Standard Time'; }
    else if (300 == summerOffset && 240 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Pakistan Standard Time'; }
    else if (300 == summerOffset && 300 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'West Asia Standard Time'; }
    else if (330 == summerOffset && 330 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'India Standard Time'; }
    else if (345 == summerOffset && 345 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Nepal Standard Time'; }
    else if (360 == summerOffset && 300 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'N. Central Asia Standard Time'; }
    else if (360 == summerOffset && 360 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Central Asia Standard Time'; }
    else if (390 == summerOffset && 390 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Myanmar Standard Time'; }
    else if (420 == summerOffset && 360 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'North Asia Standard Time'; }
    else if (420 == summerOffset && 420 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'SE Asia Standard Time'; }
    else if (480 == summerOffset && 420 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'North Asia East Standard Time'; }
    else if (480 == summerOffset && 480 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'China Standard Time'; }
    else if (540 == summerOffset && 480 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Yakutsk Standard Time'; }
    else if (540 == summerOffset && 540 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Tokyo Standard Time'; }
    else if (570 == summerOffset && 570 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Cen. Australia Standard Time'; }
    else if (570 == summerOffset && 630 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Australia/Adelaide'; }
    else if (600 == summerOffset && 540 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Asia/Yakutsk'; }
    else if (600 == summerOffset && 600 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'E. Australia Standard Time'; }
    else if (600 == summerOffset && 660 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'AUS Eastern Standard Time'; }
    else if (630 == summerOffset && 660 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Australia/Lord_Howe'; }
    else if (660 == summerOffset && 600 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Tasmania Standard Time'; }
    else if (660 == summerOffset && 660 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'West Pacific Standard Time'; }
    else if (690 == summerOffset && 690 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Central Pacific Standard Time'; }
    else if (720 == summerOffset && 660 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Magadan Standard Time'; }
    else if (720 == summerOffset && 720 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Fiji Standard Time'; }
    else if (720 == summerOffset && 780 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'New Zealand Standard Time'; }
    else if (765 == summerOffset && 825 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Pacific/Chatham'; }
    else if (780 == summerOffset && 780 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Tonga Standard Time'; }
    else if (840 == summerOffset && 840 == winterOffset) { timeZoneHiddenField = 'Pacific/Kiritimati'; }
    else { timeZoneHiddenField = 'US/Pacific'; }
    return timeZoneHiddenField;
}
```

Comment: Why do wee need two parameters (summerOffset, winterOffset)?

Comment: @PhucNguyen Some timezones observe daylight savings time, others don't.

Comment: Its like Bollywood movie!

Comment: Please note that Brazil no longer has daylight savings so this is outdated... https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/brazil

Answer (score 4):

Found this script I am using with moment.js:

http://pellepim.bitbucket.org/jstz/

This script allows to get the name of the timezone of the browser, like in this exemple:

```
> var timezone = jstz.determine();
> timezone.name(); 
"America/New_York"
```

It is not in jQuery, however...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Posting just a link, without an associated code sample, is not terribly helpful.  Please try to avoid posting just links without further information.

Comment: Unfortunately this library is not up to date, so some timezones can be detected incorrectly.

Answer (score 3):

In pure javascript using regular expression,

```
var d = new Date();
var s = d.toString();
var zoneName = s.match(".*(\\((.*)\\))")[2];
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't think of any way to do it using Jquery. You can get the remote user country name using PHP and then compare the output to:

1) an array of countries that apply light saving time (not many).

2) current date.

To get the users country:

```
function visitor_country() {
    $ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    if(filter_var(@$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
            $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    if(filter_var(@$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
            $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    $result = @json_decode(file_get_contents("http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=" . $ip))
            ->geoplugin_countryName;
    return $result <> NULL ? $result : "Unknown";
}
echo visitor_country(); // Output Country name [Ex: United States]
?>
```

This world Time Zones map link can be used to create the array:
    http://www.worldtimezone.com/daylight.html

Hope this idea works for you!

Answer (score 1):

```js
console.log(Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone);
```

```
Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone
```

Answer (score 1):

## The Modern Approach

[Matt Johnson-Pint's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18252251/775283) gives output such as `"America/Los_Angeles"` in [IANA time zone database (tzdata)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) format:

```js
Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone

// -> "America/Los_Angeles"
```

```js
console.log(Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone);
```

If you instead prefer the exact name of the timezone, like `"Pacific Standard Time"`, you can use the following expression:

```js
Intl.DateTimeFormat(undefined, { timeZoneName: "long" })
    .formatToParts(new Date())
    .find((part) => part.type === "timeZoneName").value

// -> "Pacific Standard Time"
```

```js
console.log(Intl.DateTimeFormat(undefined, { timeZoneName: "long" }).formatToParts(new Date()).find((part) => part.type === "timeZoneName").value);
```

[There are alternatives](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat#timezonename) to `{ timeZoneName: "long" }` if you prefer another format from the list:

- `"long"` -> `"Pacific Standard Time"`
- `"short"` -> `"PST"`
- `"shortOffset"` -> `"GMT-8"`
- `"longOffset"` -> `"GMT-08:00"`
- `"shortGeneric"` -> `"PT"`
- `"longGeneric"` -> `"Pacific Time"`

  ("Generic" means it won't swap between the two separately named time zones, `"Pacific Standard Time"`/`"PST"` and `"Pacific Daylight Time"`/`"PDT"`, during parts of the year.)

This should work more robustly than [Juan Mendes's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18246669/775283) because that approach works by delicately string matching the output of `(new Date()).toString()`. But all bets are off for other people using a different language, browser, or OS. The above expression should be more robust and give a translated name specific to the language of the user, like `"Nordamerikanische Westküstenzeit"` for German language users instead of `"Pacific Time"`.

This is supported in all modern browsers, even Safari. It does not work in Internet Explorer. More details in the [browser compatibility chart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/formatToParts#browser_compatibility).

Answer (score 0):

These Links might help you out [timeZone using Jquery](http://pellepim.bitbucket.org/jstz/)

or following code might help u out

```
var offset = (new Date()).getTimezoneOffset();
alert(offset);
```

checkout [JSFIddle](http://jsbin.com/adujax/2/edit) implementation or for further explanation please visit [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8090549/how-to-get-user-timezone-using-jquery) by [Scott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1244776/scott)

For Only Time Zone

```
function get_time_zone_offset( ) {
    var current_date = new Date();
  alert(current_date);   
  //return -current_date.getTimezoneOffset() / 60;

}
```

The alert popup will display Timezone as well, which you can re-factor as per your requirement, check it out in JS Fiddle

Comment: Thanks for response, but i dont want get offset number, I want to get Timezone Name like 'Pacific S.A. Standard Time, Greenwich Standard Time'.

Comment: @NathanNguyễn you can format the JS Fiddle code to return TimeZone Name as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

using moment.js + moment-timezones.js

`moment.tz.guess();`

https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/issues/138

Answer (score 0):

This site has some nice examples

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-date-now/

```
// Use of Date.now() function 
var d = Date(Date.now()); 

// Converting the number of millisecond in date string 
a = d.toString() 

// Printing the current date                     
document.write("The current date is: " + a)
```

Answer (score -1):

I know this question is old, but here's a little solution I came up with:

```
(new Date).toLocaleString('en-US', {
    hour12: false,
    hour: '2-digit',
    timeZoneName: 'long'
}).replace(/^\d\d /, '');
```

I haven't tested this widely, but for my browser this gives me:

```
"Mountain Daylight Time"
```

Hope this helps somebody out there.

Comment: @Gujamin: Sadly, you're right. It looks like Safari completely ignores the provided options object, which Chrome and other courteous browsers politely regard. Does anybody know a concise cross-platform way to obtain the timezone in long string format?

Comment: I ended up just using user3119287's answer.  Not ideal but it worked.

Comment: Not working even in IE. It does not give the timezone name

Answer (score -1):

There is no direct way, but you can do this :

var dd = new Date();
var d = dd.toString();

var startOff= d.indexOf('(') + 1;
var endOff= d.lastIndexOf(')');

var str = d.substring(startOff , endOff);

I have created a JS fiddle, where you see with alerts :
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mkj75uLy/)

```
var dd = new Date();
var d = dd.toString();

alert(d);
var startOff= d.indexOf('(') + 1;
alert(startOff);
var endOff= d.lastIndexOf(')');
alert(startOff+ "  : " + endOff);

var str = d.substring(startOff , endOff);
alert(str);
```