# JavaScript timezone information how to get America/Los_Angeles (or equivalent)

Tags: javascript, timezone

Im wondering is there a built in function in javascript that has the timezone information such as

America/Los_Angeles (or equivalent) that can be determined on whatever factor it need be factored on?

Similar to however http://momentjs.com/timezone/ does it on its home page? Or is there a list of these zones that I can attempt to build my own library off of? From what I gather http://momentjs.com/timezone/ takes the vaule America/Los_Angeles for example to determine an offset, but I can't find any mention of how to do the opposite.