# how to convert Date Object to given from UTC to any time zone like IST,WAST

Tags: java, javascript, date, datetime

i am so confuse how to do that i have a database date in UTC i want to convert in any given format by user kile IST ,WAST,CST . Iwant to know how can i do so.I am passing the zone value which is given by client here is my code :

for getting value from client i am using this:

```
var localTimeZone = new Date().getTimezone();
```

after that i want to a method which have three parameter

```
targetTimeFromZone(Date date, String fromTZ, String toTZ);
```

where fromTZ="UTC" and toTZ = "IST" or CST or any of time Zone.

Comment: `java.util.Date` doesn't have timezone with its state

Comment: so please let me know how it is possible

Comment: You've got tags of both javascript and java. They're different languages - what are you actually using? (It looks like Javascript rather than Java, but who knows.) Also note that using abbreviations for time zones is a really bad idea - they're not unique, so they don't *really* identify the zone.

Comment: thanks Jon i am using javascript in client side which give me the zone name like IST after that i am using java as a backend for get the converted date according to client

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid java.util.Date and .Calendar as they are notoriously troublesome. Use either Joda-Time or the java.time package in Java 8.

Per Jon Skeet's comment, avoid 3 or 4 letter time zone codes as they are neither standardized nor unique. Use [proper time zone names.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)

A DateTime in Joda-Time knows its own assigned time zone, unlike j.u.Date.

```
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Asia/Kolkata" ); // or get the default time zone.
```

Convert a Date to DateTime.

```
java.util.Date someDate = new java.util.Date(); // As if we were passed a Date.
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( someDate, timeZone );
```

Adjust time zone.

```
DateTime dateTimeMontréal = dateTime.withZone( DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" ) );
DateTime dateTimeUtc = dateTime.withZone( DateTimeZone.UTC );
```

If required by other classes, generate a java.util.Date object.

```
java.util.Date date = dateTime.toDate();
```

Search StackOverflow for many more examples and discussion.

Comment: thanks a lot but is there any method to pass "IST" insted of "Asia/Kolkata" means only code

Comment: @naresh Do you mean Irish Standard Time, India Standard Time, or Israel Standard Time? Reread my second paragraph and Jon Skeet's comment.

Comment: so how can i get "Asia/Kolkata" value from javascript new Date() function

Comment: @naresh I don't know anything about JavaScript. You could try searching StackOverflow, to find questions like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23546755/642706) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22618056/642706).