# Detect user timezone constant with rubyonrails activeadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone, activeadmin

I have records in database which has created_at field in UTC.
In need to show it in active_admin table as a time in user timezone.
For example:
in DB created at 2017-12-25 15:52:58
on page: 2017-12-25 15 17:52:58

I tried to use this code in activeadmin

```
paginated_collection(user_actions.page(params[:page]).per(15), download_links: false) do
            table_for(collection, sortable: false) do |action|
              column ("Timestamp"){|action| action.created_at.in_time_zone('EET').strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")}
            end
          end
```

and it works fine. But I need to get user timezone constant programmatically to pass it into

```
in_time_zone(timezone_variable)
```

or

```
in_time_zone(get_current_timezone_method)
```

I tried to get it like this

```
Time.zone.now.name
```

but it doesn't work and I think it because this code try to get server timezone but not a client.
**Is there any way to get client timezone on client side and display created_at in active_admin which include timezone correction?**
Also (if previous way is impossible) I thought about another way - to store users timezone in DB when user signed in. And get it from DB to pass into

```
in_time_zone(action.user.timezone)
```

. **Is there any way to get users timezone constant in controller action on server side to store it in DB?**

Answer (score 1):

This is a common Rails problem with no good answer. You can try [setting a header with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13/determine-a-users-timezone) but the simplest way is to have the user manually set their preferred timezone in their user profile.

Comment: Yes, JS is the only way.  A better approach though is documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22618056/javascript-timezone-information-how-to-get-america-los-angeles-or-equivalent).