# How to get the client timezone using moment-timezone.js

Tags: timezone, momentjs

How I can get the client timezone using moment-timezone.js or moment.js ?

Thanks!

Comment: These are the questions that annoy me the most

Comment: Google your question and you will see the answer

Comment: Show us what work you have done before asking for help

Comment: @DanielF google it for me, I will be happy if you can find something :) If it annoy you don't waste your time writing a beautiful comment like that. appreciate your help ...

Comment: My point is, why can't you Google it yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is feature is not currently available, but is planned for a future release.  See:

- https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/issues/55
- https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/issues/138
- https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/pull/220

In the meantime, consider [jsTimeZoneDetect](http://pellepim.bitbucket.org/jstz/)

See also: [Can I get the name of the time zone of the client by using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18252251/634824)

Answer (score 0):

Checking the issue list above, I found that detecting the user timezone is available, although it is not very very correct.

```
moment.tz.guess()
>> "Europe/Budapest"    // when actually I am in Madrid, but I think it is due to some historical reason
```

According to the discussion and having checked the src (0.5), it is based on `Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone`, and is believed to be the most corrected way, and is supported by many modern(proper) browsers, see list: https://caniuse.com/#feat=internationalization

Afortunately Budapest uses the same DST time as Madrid. If you have a target user group geographically wider distributed, I suggest more precaution to be taken.