# Add timezone to Calendar DateTime picker using jquery

Tags: jquery, date, datetime, calendar

I am using Jquery datetime picker for calendar display

```js
var today = new Date();  
jQuery('.strathidden , .endhidden').datetimepicker({
         minDate:today
});
```

I want to add `timezone` to this component so that the `calendar` should come with respect to the timezone.

Say for example
if in `India` the date is `29/02/2016 14:37:20 PM` so when calendar is open it should point to the current and time of India but if my timezone is in different zone for example `GMT-7` so its current date is `29/02/2016 14:10:20 AM` so the calendar points to the current date of `GMT-7` timezone.

Comment: First of all it's not a good idea nor it is possible to get the timezone using javascript or jquery from a browser for more better explanation click [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18252251/3855179). So you need to get the timezone using the server logic. Once you get the timezone, i would suggest you to use moment js to convert the date-time and pass it to the datetime picker.

Comment: Thanks Sumit can you elaborate more about the to get timezone using the server logic