# How to get the client timezone id for c# timezoneinfo class from client side using javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, datetime, timezone

I want to get client timezone id from JavaScript  to parse c# TimezoneInfo class.And Convert to utc time.And I have this

```
var timezone = String(new Date());
return timezone.substring(timezone.lastIndexOf('(') + 1).replace(')', '').trim();
```

Problem is some time it will javascript timezone return CST. Is there a proper way to get timezone id

and from the c#

```
TimeZoneInfo ZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZoneIdFromJavascript);
return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(Datetime, ZoneInfo);'
```

Comment: I want to detect client timeZone id to convert to UTC

Comment: `new Date().getTimezoneOffset()` will tell you mins from GMT. also the `date.toISOString()` is the same everywhere, which makes it more reliable to chop up (it's already in gmt).

Comment: My javascript function work for me in my country but some users got CST.Someone tell me what is CST.Why im getting this.and how to solve this

Comment: the string version of dates is locale-specific and un-specified; you cannot use pieces of it. i already showed you how to get the offset, you can divide that by 60 if you want hours instead of mins... CST is Central Standard Time, which is the timezone here in chicago, so it makes sense to me when i see it, just like a human-targeted date format should...

Comment: Thanks  many for your answer.

Answer (score 14):

1. `TimeZoneInfo` uses *Windows* time zone identifiers.  They are not going to match anything coming out of JavaScript.  Please read [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).
2. Identifying the user's time zone in JavaScript is imperfect.  You can *guess* at it, using [one of these methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18252251/634824), but that is going to give you an IANA time zone id, not a Windows time zone id.
3. You can convert IANA time zones to Windows time zones using either my [TimeZoneConverter](https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneConverter) library, or the method [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17348807/634824) which uses [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org).  However if you're going to use Noda Time, you might as well just use IANA time zones in the first place.  Noda Time does a much better job than `TimeZoneInfo`.
4. If you just want to convert the client's local time to UTC, then just do that in the browser in JavaScript.  Then you don't need to know what the local time zone actually is.

Comment: Thanks matt for your answer.This is very help full to me.

Comment: Just as an update, please note this was the correct answer in 2016.  Nowadays, `TimeZoneInfo` uses IANA identifiers on MacOS and Linux, and Windows identifiers on Windows.  But it can also convert between them on any OS.  See [my blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/date-time-and-time-zone-enhancements-in-net-6/#time-zone-conversion-apis) for more details.

Answer (score 4):

The safest way I've found is to use only the offset amount from the UTC and not the identifier name.

From Javascript I send this:

```
var dateString = new Date();
var offset = dateString.getTimezoneOffset();
```

And on the C# I map this offset to the first Time Zone that has the same offset:

```
string jsNumberOfMinutesOffset = ViewModel.offset;   // sending the above offset
var timeZones = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones();
var numberOfMinutes =  Int32.Parse(jsNumberOfMinutesOffset)*(-1);
var timeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(numberOfMinutes);
var userTimeZone = timeZones.Where(tz => tz.BaseUtcOffset == timeSpan).FirstOrDefault();
```

This gives us the first timezone which has the same offset received from the client side. Since there are more than one time zones with the same offset it does not always matches the exact time zone of the user but it is completely reliable to convert from UTC to local representation of time.

I'm hoping it helps someone :)

Comment: This does not work for timezones with DST