# Get timezone from users browser using moment(timezone).js

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs, moment-timezone, angular-moment

What is the best way to get client's timezone and convert it to some other timezone when using moment.js and moment-timezone.js

I want to find out what is clients timezone and later convert his date and time into some other timezone.

Does anybody has experience with this?

Comment: Now since moment is discontinued. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/34602679/4050261 for super simple one liner without any libraries.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
var timedifference = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
```

This returns the difference from the clients timezone from UTC time. 
You can then play around with it as you like.

Comment: This returns the *current* time zone *offset*.  Not the time zone.  The offset can change, based on things like daylight saving time.  See "Time Zone != Offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info)

Comment: @MattJohnson's answer is the true answer to this question. Technically this answer is incorrect as it is offset-related, not timezone-related (different concepts).

Comment: This doesn't work in Firefox, new Date() creates a date object in UTC timezone, so it is pointless to getTimezoneOffset() on it

Comment: So how do we play around with it with moment?

Comment: @KrzysztofKrasoń I just tried this and it does in fact work in both Chrome and Firefox (version 104.0.2).

Answer (score 306):

When using moment.js, use:

```
var tz = moment.tz.guess();
```

It will return an IANA time zone identifier, such as `America/Los_Angeles` for the US Pacific time zone.

It is [documented here](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/guessing-user-timezone/).

Internally, it first tries to get the time zone from the browser using the following call:

```
Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone
```

If you are targeting only modern browsers that support this function, and you don't need Moment-Timezone for anything else, then you can just call that directly.

If Moment-Timezone doesn't get a valid result from that function, or if that function doesn't exist, then it will "guess" the time zone by testing several different dates and times against the `Date` object to see how it behaves.  The guess is usually a good enough approximation, but not guaranteed to exactly match the time zone setting of the computer.

Comment: See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16526897/634824) and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18252251/634824).

Comment: Great answer - Upvoted! Also please use `momet-timezone` version **0.5.4** or higher... please follow this thread for further explanations https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/issues/324

Comment: +1. Make sure your using moment with date to utilize the tz hook. https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/ to installed it with node.js use this command `npm install moment-timezone` then required it like this `window.moment = require('moment-timezone');`

Comment: It's really important that people know: this is the correct answer. The currently accepted answer gives you timezone OFFSET (a `+/-INT` value) , not the timezone (a string like "America/Los Angeles"). They are two totally different concepts.

Comment: Is the timezone taken from the browser or the device?

Comment: @bubble - It's taken from whichever environment the code is executing in.

Comment: from [the wiki tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info): *One can determine the correct offset, given a time zone and a datetime. But one cannot determine the correct time zone given just an offset.*. then, can one determine the correct time zone given an offset AND a datetime? if yes, couldn't one determine the correct (current) time zone in a browser given the client's offset and current datetime? thanks

Comment: @Scaramouche - That's not related to what's being asked here.  Please don't chain on to old comments, but rather ask a new question.  (short answer - no, you still cannot)

Answer (score 9):

All current answers provide the offset differece at current time, not at a given date.

`moment(date).utcOffset()` returns the time difference in minutes between browser time and UTC ***at the date passed as argument*** (or today, if no date passed).

Here's a function to parse correct offset at the picked date:

```
function getUtcOffset(date) {
  return moment(date)
    .subtract(
      moment(date).utcOffset(), 
      'minutes')
    .utc()
}
```

Comment: The function is actually `utcOffset()`, not `offsetUtc()` :)

Comment: @Milkncookiez, I updated the answer. Thank you. No idea how I inverted them (it might be a case of working both ways or being changed in some prior version - the probability of me posting something I haven't tested is close to `null`).

Answer (score 7):

Using **Moment** library, see their website -> https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/converting-to-zone/

*i notice they also user their own library in their website, so you can have a try using the browser console before installing it*

```
moment().tz(String);

The moment#tz mutator will change the time zone and update the offset.

moment("2013-11-18").tz("America/Toronto").format('Z'); // -05:00
moment("2013-11-18").tz("Europe/Berlin").format('Z');   // +01:00

This information is used consistently in other operations, like calculating the start of the day.

var m = moment.tz("2013-11-18 11:55", "America/Toronto");
m.format();                     // 2013-11-18T11:55:00-05:00
m.startOf("day").format();      // 2013-11-18T00:00:00-05:00
m.tz("Europe/Berlin").format(); // 2013-11-18T06:00:00+01:00
m.startOf("day").format();      // 2013-11-18T00:00:00+01:00

Without an argument, moment#tz returns:

    the time zone name assigned to the moment instance or
    undefined if a time zone has not been set.

var m = moment.tz("2013-11-18 11:55", "America/Toronto");
m.tz();  // America/Toronto
var m = moment.tz("2013-11-18 11:55");
m.tz() === undefined;  // true
```

Comment: TypeError: time.tz is not a function ```const time = moment().format('YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss'); time.tz()```

Answer (score 2):

if the user's timezone is all you wanted then

```
const localtz = moment.tz.guess() // returns user's timezone
```

Additionally if you wanted to use it then the best way to convert a timestamp to user's timezone is

```
const time = moment.tz(response.timestamp)
const localtz = moment.tz.guess() // user's timezone
const date = time.clone().tz(localtz) // convert time to user's timezone
```

here `localtz` is the user's timezone and using it we can convert the timestamp to user's local time

Answer (score 1):

You can also get your wanted time using the following JS code:

```
new Date(`${post.data.created_at} GMT+0200`)
```

In this example, my received dates were in GMT+0200 timezone. Instead of it can be every single timezone. And the returned data will be the date in your timezone. Hope this will help anyone to save time

Comment: You cannot get client timezone that way.

Answer (score 0):

```js
moment().format("MMM DD YYYY")
```

This will provide the time zone of the application, not the system.

Answer (score -1):

First, you can find out the clients time zone using the following

`let zoneVal =  moment().tz(Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone).format('Z')`

it will return you the GMT zone format for example +5:30 (colombo/srilanka & Delhi/India) or +6:00(Dhaka Bangladesh)  depending on the region you are in.

secondly,
if you want to find out the time of a particular time zone , then do the following

`moment.tz("Asia/Dhaka").format()`

which will return you the time zone value in ISO format of Dhaka.

Answer (score -1):

Using moment timezone you can get easily your local date-time

```
moment().utcOffset(0, true).format()
```