# Moment.js - how to get user time zone?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I want to set current time zone with `moment.js` for user that runs my app. My problem is that many of momentjs question posted here have method called `tz` but I can't see it now in 2020.

[Format date in a specific timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15347589/format-date-in-a-specific-timezone)

With that method you can set this:

```
moment().tz('America/Phoeinx')
```

But I don't want to set this manually. I found `utc` method but it returns me timezone +0000.

How to set current time zone with momentjs in 2020?

Comment: `Date.prototype.getTimezoneOffset()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get timezone from users browser using moment(timezone).js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40401543/get-timezone-from-users-browser-using-momenttimezone-js)

Comment: You could try [`moment.tz.guess()`](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/guessing-user-timezone/)

Comment: @Aivaras I need to use momentjs not Date

Comment: @wgumenyuk tz is no longer available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found an answer, all that we need is just get current utcOffset from momentjs library:

```
const currentUtcOffset = moment().utcOffset()
```

and pass it to `utc` method

```
moment(date).utc(currentUtcOffset).toISOString()
```

Now everything works perfect.