# How to get client side timezone id in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I need to get client side timezone using JavaScript. I am using below code.

```
new Date().toString().split('(')[1].slice(0, -1)
```

But it returns timezone daylightname, and I need id.

For example, client side timezone as set as `(UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)` and I need to get output as `Eastern Standard Time`. But I am getting `Eastern Daylight Time` as output.

Can I do this without any additional plugin requirements?

Comment: Perhaps this can help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091372/getting-the-clients-timezone-in-javascript

Comment: You may want to look at [How can I get the timezone name in JavaScript?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat/resolvedOptions).

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18246547/get-name-of-time-zone

Comment: Those are not exactly matches with my requirement. Most of comments code including new date() method which will return daylight name not standard name of timezone

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
var objdatetime = new Date();
var timezone = objdatetime.toTimeString();
var tzstr = timezone.split("(");
var timezoneid = tzstr[1].toString().replace(")","");
alert(timezoneid);
```

Comment: No, this is also returning daylightname only not standard name

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
new Date().toString().split('(')[1].slice(0, -1).replace('Daylight', 'Standard')
```